# Installing Cortana/Speech VCD On Windows 10 Anniversary Update Fails

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, cortana

I noticed this all throughout the Insider Preview for Windows 10 Anniversary Edition and just assumed it would be resolved, however a call to InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync() always fails with "The system cannot find the file specified" on any machine running W10 Anniversary Edition. This is true regardless of the target version (10240, 10586, 14393).

So, any apps that integrate with Cortana seems to now be unable to integrate with Cortana.

Anyone know of what the issue might be or if there is a different supported method for registering voice commands with Cortana now via UWP?

Comment: Have you tried the official [Cortana voice command sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand) on GitHub? It works well on my side. I'm using Windows 10 Anniversary Update Build 14393.10.

Comment: Jay, yes, and on all our machines, even fresh builds of 14393. We can take even this simplest scenario and it fails. In fact, this is an issue I've been trying to overcome for months and have seen other users have the issue with AE. The minute we attempt to deploy any app that has worked without issue into AE (even in early builds) it fails on that line of code. Other 3rd part apps (like even Netflix) fail to install voice commands. I wonder what is different with your environment vs. any of our machines?

Comment: As a note, I'm not a newbie to Cortana development. In fact I am the developer of Cortana and the creator of the Mastering Cortana Development series for Wintellect, so it has to be something specifically with ALL the machines people are testing on vs. your environment. I can deploy anything perfectly on a non-AE build right now, and then when we deploy to a AE machine it fails every time, no matter what. These are also all standalone machines, and no policies are in place that could affect anything. Fresh build, deploy...issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: BTW, I meant "Cortanium" not Cortana in the post above. Here is an image using the 3rd iHeartRadio app that demonstrates the issue with other apps as well: http://www.liquiddaffodil.com/Cortanium/NOTInstallVCAE.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something is fundamentally broken on whatever image you are using to setup Windows.

So I have some questions need your answer:

1. What OS image (ISO) are you using to setup the machines? Is it from MSDN subscription or somewhere else?
2. Is this an actual machine or a Virtual machine. If Virtual, is it Hyper-V based or some other fancy emulation (like VMWare).
3. If this is an actual hardware based machine, what is the machine type/information.

And if you can grab a capture using the script at [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkIg4z63jtyY50Mj-1VL6gRsDspG), please share with us by following these steps:

1. Unzip the **trace.zip** file
2. Run the **CaptureEtlTrace.ps1** script, maybe you need to change Execution Policy to enable execution, see https://superuser.com/questions/106360/how-to-enable-execution-of-powershell-scripts
3. Get the **.etl** file(Check Log Filename) and share with us
   [image]

We will check this file to see which component is the culprit:)

**----------Update(08/16/2016)-----------**

Thank you for your reporting, this unknown issue has been filed. The related team is working on investigating it and making the patch for future release.

Comment: 1. These are all hardware based machines. All just Dell laptops.
2. All original Windows 10 installations were from the 64-bit en-US MSDN Pro .ISO. Here is the ZIP of the ETL:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhLGvYHqB5ZQmOcQr9CxCB4Rv10ArQ Thanks brother!

Comment: Franklin, just wondering if you had any more insight on a possible resolution on this?

Comment: I am seeing the exact same problem on Windows 10, Version 1607, Build 14393.447. Any update on the issue @FranklinChen-MSFT ?